# BLAS library dpendency issues with Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk, blas

I am building an android application (targeting ARMv8) with native c++ code that calls functions from Blaze library(https://bitbucket.org/blaze-lib/blaze).

To have interface with blaze library, I added the following code in CMakeLists.txt under app directory:

```
set( blaze_src_DIR ../../../lib_source/blaze )
set( blaze_build_DIR ../../../lib_source/blaze/outputs )
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${blaze_build_DIR})
add_subdirectory(${blaze_src_DIR} ${blaze_build_DIR} )

find_package( blaze )
if( blaze_FOUND )
   add_library( blaze_target INTERFACE )
  target_link_libraries( blaze_target INTERFACE blaze::blaze )
  message(STATUS "Added blaze library")
else()
  message(STATUS "Still Could not add blaze library")
endif()
```

lib_source/blaze does contain CMakeLists.txt and I followed the instructions for blaze installation guide itself

Now the problem is with gradle sync. cmake tries to find BLAS library using FindBLAS.cmake module, which gives a FATAL error: A library with BLAS API not found. Please specify library location.

I tried installing several BLAS libraries but to no help.
ATLAS does not come with cmake, opeBLAS does have a cmake but requires gfortran to compile it. This will required ndk-bundle toolchain to support gfortran. I found this link to get those: https://www.bountysource.com/issues/48354321-how-to-link-openblas-for-armv7-by-cmake-in-android-studio

The above process is very tedious and long. My question is: what is the simpler way (in my settings) to get Blaze library work with or without BLAS support? Are there pre-built library that I can use? If yes, please describe the procedure.

Some helpful links I found, but could not figure out exact solution to my problem:

1. [sourceforge.net/projects/openblas/files/v0.2.8-arm/]
2. [github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/wiki/How-to-build-OpenBLAS-for-Android]
3. [jcsilva.github.io/2017/03/18/compile-kaldi-android/]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My company has a prebuilt and a conan.io recipe for building OpenBLAS. It doesn't take too long to become familiar with the conan.io tooling and then you would be able to write a conan recipe for Blaze that consumes my OpenBLAS package. https://bintray.com/slidewavellc/conan-libs/OpenBLAS%3Aslidewave

Answer (score 1):

If you are not particularly tied to OpenBLAS or ATLAS, then you can find some prebuilt BLAS libraries in the [release section](https://github.com/jeti/android_ipopt/releases) of this repo: https://github.com/jeti/android_ipopt.